# Windows 10 Login With Companion Device

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

I am trying to create my own custom login with a cellphone.
I've used the example project from Microsoft github repository - [*companion-device-framework*](https://github.com/Microsoft/companion-device-framework).

I am facing a problem in which the app act differently in every computer.
The background task hits many times.
In the following picture the Performing Auth is calling multiple times, and it cause the authentication to fail.

[image: As you can see Performing Auth is calling multiple times]

any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: I tested the sample in my side and it worked well. I'm using VS 2017 and I changed the project's target to 15063. Do you have the same issue in every computer? And in your screenshot, it shows "Auth completed", what do you mean "it cause the authentication to fail"?

Comment: I've tested it in 5 different computers, and in every device it is acting differently. I'm also using VS 2017. Just after "Auth completed" there is another toast "unexpected error". The CDF demo do work but those background tasks appeared more than once per session. In my demo those multiple background ruin my flow.